# Simbolo euro word

Tags: java, apache-poi

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
XWPFParagraph totalFinal = documento.createParagraph();
XWPFRun tileFinal = totalFinal.createRun();
tileFinal.setText("TOTAL: " + totalIVA + " (€) ");
```

cuando genero el word, me sale un símbolo raro

Comment: Por si te sirve. El hecho de que usar la representación en unicode te funcionó indica de que el problema radica con el encoding de tu archivo *.java*. Si cambiaras su encoding a UTF-8, seguramente no tendrías el problema.

Comment: y como cambio eso?

Comment: Depende del IDE que usas. Eclipse, NetBeans, otro?

Comment: ok veo que es en el resources, cambio cp1252 por utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes probar a usar lo siguiente:

```
String euro = " \u20AC"; //Símbolo del euro en unicode
XWPFParagraph totalFinal = documento.createParagraph();
XWPFRun tileFinal = totalFinal.createRun();
tileFinal.setText("TOTAL: " + totalIVA + euro);
```

Comment: muchas gracias!